# How to uninstall steam64 for linux/ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, steam

I'm seeing people say things like `sudo apt-get remove steam` and `sudo dpkg -r steam` but neither are working.

I ran `dpkg-query -l *steam*` and I get the following:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  steam          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
rc  steam-launcher 1.0.0.47     all          Launcher for the Steam software d
un  steam64        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Not sure if this helps.

The steam FAQ doesn't seem to help either. I'm pretty sure I didn't do any `apt-get` install for Steam. I downloaded the `steam_latest.deb` from the website. Any ideas?

Update: I do have what I believe to be the folder in `~/.steam`. What I'm wondering now is, if I remove this folder, what else do I need to remove?

Comment: yeah get rid of that folder, it's not needed

Comment: I must've succeeded in uninstalling by uninstalling the launcher. It just didn't feel as if I was actually removing if I removed a launcher. The entire folder in `~/.steam` contained all the files necessary to launch the application so I was confused as to how I could uninstall properly and wasn't sure if a simple `rm -rf ~/.steam` would have been enough.

Comment: "~/." files usually only contain user settings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge steam-launcher && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Post any errors to recieve further assistance.

Comment: `Package 'steam64' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED
  steam-launcher*` have done this - but doesn't feel like I'm done.

Comment: I think removing `steam-launcher` must've done the trick. The only thing that remains is that the actual install of Steam in `~/.steam` remains so, I'm assuming if I delete this, I'm all done?

Comment: When you run `purge`, as opposed to `remove`, you delete the configuration files as well completely removing the program. The `remove` command leaves the configuration files intact so if you re-install the program all your previous settings will still be in place.

Comment: Good idea. I'm actually using lubuntu so I'll search with pcmanfm but it has the same functionality as nautilus. I also tried a quick `locate steam` and halted it before it went mad, I could see I also have a copy of Steam in `~/.local/share/Steam` which makes me want to facepalm a little.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing Synaptic Package Manager with `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, then open the program and search for `steam`. Click the little button next to it and/or other packages you wish to remove and mark it/them for complete removal, then press Apply. This generally does a more thorough job of removing applications.

Comment: Synaptic doesn't come up with any results. This is odd.

Comment: if synaptic doesn't show results, what's the output of `dpkg -l | grep steam`?

Comment: If Synaptic hasn't got any results, you've probably succeeded in removing the program earlier.

Comment: @mchid no output.

Comment: You might be able to still run the purge command to remove all of the configuration files. If not it won't hurt.