# Cannot Uninstall Steam

Tags: 14.10, steam

How do I unistall steam?

`sudo apt-get remove steam` returns `Package 'steam:i386' is not installed, so not removed` This response seems odd because this is a 64 bit system and I steam runs fine when I open it in a terminal.

Steam shows up in the software center when I search for it but clicking more info it says Not Found.

What is going on?

Comment: SEE http://askubuntu.com/questions/471318/how-to-uninstall-steam64-for-linux-ubuntu Mind though ~/steam is a user config and will not be removed unless you use purge.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing `sudo apt-get install steam` then remove it again.

Comment: I was able to install steam and remove steam that way but after remove and purging steam. I can still run it from a terminal and the icon was not removed from the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Remove steam-launcher. `sudo apt-get remove steam-launcher` Not sure why it is separate from removing steam.